# Login with google api in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, gmail

I'm coding function login with google api on Wordpress(by myself not plugins) but i have an issues. Ideas follow:
1. Get token from google to get information (i did).
2. Compare email with account.If result is true, log in without password account.
I have an issue in step 2. result return true but i don't understand why page overload. I using debug to check value but nothing wrong.When i remove function "loggIn()", code ran. 
Here's my code: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVDVJ.png)

Comment: Please do not post links to pictures in lieu of posting your actual code in the body of the original question.  Thank you.

Comment: thanks for feedback. i will do in the next time.

Answer (score 1):

For a while I made something similar for the backend.

```
<?php
public function uty_main_page(){
    require_once ('config.php');
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $token_decode = json_decode($_SESSION['token']);
        update_option( 'uty_refresh_token' , $token_decode->refresh_token );
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
        echo 'Authorization Successful';
    }
    ?>
                    <?php if(get_option( 'uty_refresh_token' ) != ''){ ?>
                        <li><a href="#uty_upload">Upload</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#uty_videos">All Videos</a></li>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <li><a href="#uty_settings">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="tab_content">
                <?php if( $client->isAccessTokenExpired() ) { ?>
                    <?php if(get_option( 'uty_refresh_token' ) != ''){ ?>
                        <?php
                        $client->refreshToken( get_option( 'uty_refresh_token' ) );
                        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
                        $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken());
                        ?>
                        <div id="uty_upload">
                            <?php
                            if(isset($_POST['uty_video_submit'])){
                                if(isset($_FILES['uty_video'])){
                                    $uploaded = media_handle_upload('uty_video', 0);
                                    if(is_wp_error($uploaded)){
                                        $message = $uploaded->get_error_message();
                                    }
                                    else{
                                            //Do Some coding here
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <div id="uty_settings">
                    <?php if(isset($_POST['revoke-access-token'])){ ?>
                        <?php update_option( 'uty_refresh_token' , '' ); ?>
                        <?php update_option( 'uty_google_client_api' , '' ); ?>
                        <?php update_option( 'uty_google_client_id' , '' ); ?>
                        <?php update_option( 'uty_google_client_secret' , '' ); ?>
                        <?php update_option( 'uty_youtube_channel' , '' ); ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <h3>Please enter the below details to kick start your Youtube uploads</h3>

                    <?php if( !empty(get_option('uty_google_client_api')) && !empty(get_option('uty_google_client_id')) && !empty(get_option('uty_google_client_secret')) && empty(get_option('uty_refresh_token')) ){ ?>
                            <?php $state = mt_rand(); ?>
                            <?php $client->setState($state); ?>
                            <?php $_SESSION['state'] = $state; ?>
                            <?php $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl(); ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $authUrl; ?>">Click here to authorize your credentials</a>
                    <?php } elseif( !empty(get_option('uty_google_client_api')) && !empty(get_option('uty_google_client_id')) && !empty(get_option('uty_google_client_secret')) && !empty(get_option('uty_refresh_token')) ){ ?>

                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

In the above function the main thing i've done is to store refresh_token when user logs in first time and then pass it in function to get new access token every time.

```
$client->refreshToken( get_option( 'uty_refresh_token' ) );
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken());
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks bro for answer, but i have been taken token from google. i had an email but when i check that email to login via Wordpress. It's not working